# Cannot insert multiple items into SQLite database

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

The DB has a primary table for batch data, each Batch can have zero or more Samples. They are linked on Batch.BatchID == Samples.FK_BatchID. The Classes for these tables are shown below.

I can add a value to Batches - the autoincrement BatchID updates as expected.
I can add a single value to the Samples.
I cannot add multiple values to the Samples table and get an exception with

> Additional information: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.

If I set STOP to '1' then the db gets a new Batch with a properly referenced new Sample. What must I do to allow multiple Samples to be added for a single Batch. In addition, I'd ideally like to use the same context and a single 'SubmitChanges()' operation - but let me walk before I run.

Here is the code I've attempted:

```
 Int64 newbatchID = 0;
 using (var context = new Data.BatchContext(connection))
 {    // This 'chunk' work fine and the newbatchID gets the new value
      context.Log = Console.Out;
      Data.Batches newBatch = new Data.Batches {
           Created = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("u"),
           Title = "New Title",
           Varietal = "Waltz"
      };

      // Return the Batch Id if necessary...
      var qs = from c in context.sqlite_sequence
               where c.name == "Batches"
               select c.seq;
      context.Batches.InsertOnSubmit(newBatch);
      context.SubmitChanges();
      newbatchID = qs.ToList().First();
 }

 // Use the new batch ID to submit a load of new samples
 int STOP = 2;     // PROBLEM. If Stop is not 1 the following fails
 using (var context = new Data.BatchContext(connection))
 {
      context.Log = Console.Out;
      List<Data.Samples> samplelist = new List<Data.Samples>();
      for (var i = 0; i < STOP; ++i)
      {    // Just to get different time values
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
           samplelist.Add(
                new Data.Samples {
                     // Commenting out the FK_BatchID doesn't help
                     FK_BatchID = newbatchID,
                     Created = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("u"),
                     ImageURI = String.Format("./Path/Img_{0}.jpg", i)
                });
           }
           context.Samples.InsertAllOnSubmit(samplelist);
           context.SubmitChanges();
      }
```

Data base classes

```
[Table(Name = "Batches")]
public class Batches
{
    public virtual ICollection<Batches> batches { get; set; }
    public Batches()
    {
        batches = new HashSet<Batches>();
    }

    // Primary key - nullable to allow Autoincrement
    [Column(Name = "BatchID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Int64? BatchID { get; set; }

    // Batch creation date
    [Column(Name = "Created")]
    public String Created { get; set; }

    // Other String columns the same as Created
    ...
}

[Table(Name = "Samples")]
public class Samples
{
    public virtual ICollection<Samples> samples { get; set; }
    public Samples()
    {
        samples = new HashSet<Samples>();
    }

    // Primary key - nullable to allow Autoincrement
    [Column(Name = "SampleID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Int64? SampleID { get; set; }

    // Foreign key to the Batches Table
    private EntityRef<Batches> _batch = new EntityRef<Batches>();
    [Association(Name = "FK_BatchID", IsForeignKey = true, 
                 Storage = "_batch", ThisKey = "FK_BatchID", 
                  OtherKey = "BatchID")]
    public Batches Batches
    {
        get { return _batch.Entity; }
        set { _batch.Entity = value; }
    }
    // Foreign key table entry
    [Column(Name = "FK_BatchID")]
    public Int64? FK_BatchID { get; set; }

    // Date the image was processed by the batch
    [Column(Name = "Created")]
    public String Created { get; set; }
    
    // Other String columns etc
    ...
 }
```

---

### Edit:

After unsuccessfully trying modifications to the Column adornment (i.e. IsDbGenerated and/or DbType etc) I've implemented a work around using sqlite_sequence shown below. This is used to find values for the various table ID's which are then used when creating the new objects. These can then all be wrapped up in a single transaction

```
 // Start by getting the latest autoincrement values
 var aiQuery = (from c in context.sqlite_sequence
                select c).ToList();

 Int64 batchId = 1 + aiQuery.Find(q => q.name == @"Batches").seq;
 Int64 sampleId = 1 + aiQuery.Find(q => q.name == @"Samples").seq;
 
 // Create objects etc
 ...

 // Then update the db once only
 context.Batches.InsertOnSubmit(newBatch);
 context.SubmitChanges();
```

If there are no better solutions then I'll accept this as the answer

Comment: Doesn't `Batch` have a `Samples` collection to which you can add new samples?

Comment: @Gert: Yes, using the hacky use of sqlite_sequence allows a new Batch with multiple Samples to be added in a single transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of a proper solution here is my workaround.

Use sql_sequence to establish autoincrement Id values which are then used explicitly in the objects being created.

```
var aiQuery = (from sequence in sqlite_sequence
               select sequence).ToList();

BatchId = 1 + aiQuery.Find(q => q.name == @"Batches").seq;
SampleId = 1 + aiQuery.Find(q => q.name == @"Samples").seq;
```

For convenience I placed this in my class deriving from Linq.DataContext

---

Then multiple inserts can be added in a single transaction as per the following pseudo code.

```
Batch batch = new Batch { id = BatchId, ... }
foreach (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
{
   batch.AddSample(new Sample { id = SampleId+i, batchid = BatchId, ... });
}

// Update db
context.Batches.InsertOnSubmit(batch);
context.SubmitChanges();
```