# Insert with AutoIncrement

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I am trying to insert some data into my SQLite database which works perfectly when I do this with one record. But inside a loop I get an Error. First, here is the code

```
string dataSource = "Data Source=";
Connection = new SQLiteConnection(dataSource + this.DatabasePath);

var context = new DataContext(Connection);

var users = context.GetTable<User>();


for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    User tempUser = new User() {
        ID = null,
        EMail = i + "@" + i + ".de",
        Password = "Test1234",
        JoinedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
    };

    users.InsertOnSubmit(tempUser);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

And the User itself

```
[Table(Name = "User")]
public class User {

    [Column(Name = "UserID", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = false)]
    public int? ID { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "EMail", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string EMail { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Password", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "JoinedDate", CanBeNull = false)]
    public String JoinedDate { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "PaymentMethodID")]
    public int PaymentMethodID { get; set; }
}
```

The Table is created like this

```
CREATE TABLE "User" (
`UserID`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`EMail` TEXT NOT NULL,
`Password`  TEXT NOT NULL,
`JoinedDate`    TEXT NOT NULL,
`Licenses`  INTEGER,
`PaymentMethodID`   INTEGER
)
```

And finally the Error I get:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Eine Entität, deren Schlüssel bereits verwendet wird, kann nicht hinzugefügt werden.

I could bet, that this is happening because of the Field `ID`, which is set to `AutoIncrement`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error using System.Data.Linq.Mapping and auto incrementing the primary key in a sqlite db](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665788/error-using-system-data-linq-mapping-and-auto-incrementing-the-primary-key-in-a)

Comment: You should have `public int ID { get; set; }` (not nullable) and mark the property as `DatabaseGenerated` = `Identity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your code works fine with one insert, I would try one of these solutions

**Solution 1**

call `context.SubmitChanges();` outside of the loop

so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    User tempUser = new User() {
        ID = null,
        EMail = i + "@" + i + ".de",
        Password = "Test1234",
        JoinedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
    };

    users.InsertOnSubmit(tempUser);

}
context.SubmitChanges();
```

**Solution 2**

use `InsertAllOnSubmit`

```
var tempUsers = Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
                      .Select(i => new User{
                                   ID = null,
                                   EMail = i + "@" + i + ".de",
                                   Password = "Test1234",
                                   JoinedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
                      });

users.InsertAllOnSubmit(tempUsers);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

**Solution 3**

Dispose and recreate context in each loop (seems a rather bad idea)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
   using (var context = new DataContext(Connection)) {
     var users = context.GetTable<User>();

     User tempUser = new User() {

        ID = null,
        EMail = i + "@" + i + ".de",
        Password = "Test1234",
        JoinedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
    };

     users.InsertOnSubmit(tempUser);
     context.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

Comment: Only Solution 3 worked for me. But is this a good solution? Especially when keeping speed in mind

Comment: @DanielDirtyNativeMartin No, it's not... Another way, maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145955/cannot-insert-multiple-items-into-sqlite-database

Answer (score 0):

You just remove ID = null, Because this is Auto-increment and not need to write this.
Alter table "User" remove NOT NULL check in Auto-increment column ID and also remove in class "User". ID column is Auto-increment then not need check with NOT NULL constraint.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    User tempUser = new User() {
        EMail = i + "@" + i + ".de",
        Password = "Test1234",
        JoinedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss")
    };
```

Comment: I did, but still the same Error

Comment: Please remove NOT NULL check in UserID   => `UserID`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

Comment: You need to remove from both table "User" and class "User"

Comment: Sure, i did. I also added `[Column(Name = "UserID", IsPrimaryKey = true, CanBeNull = true)]` above `UserID`

Comment: Please use like this [Column(Name = "UserID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY")]

Comment: with @NitinChotaliya piece of code I am getting the error `An exception of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database

near "SELECT": syntax error`

Comment: Please edit the code and use like this [Column(Name = "UserID", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]